# Is this really an efficient algorithm?

Tags: python

I have read, but I do not understand.

I would like to see some code like Python or Java... but i can't find it... Could you give me some code for this algorithm?

Comment: It's not supposed to be efficient, it's supposed to shuffle items that are part of categories (songs by the same artist) so as to maximally spread out the items from the same category, because people **perceive** this as more random.

Comment: How about speed ? I do not know if I implemented it properly, but the more music there is, the slower it will be.

Comment: What implementation are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the algorithm described in this blog. I want to see it in code.
But I do not have much ability to implement. can you help me ?

Comment: Spotify hasn't used that algorithm in years. They rewrote their clients and didn't bring this algorithm over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify does not give any code for or give a name for the algorithm they used, but I've accepted your challenge, and have written some code that implements their algorithm.

For anyone who is reading this who was to lazy to read the article. Spotify's random function caused songs by the same artist to be played 2-3 times in a row, and people complained that their algorithm wasn't random enough. Below is the algorithm that was outlined in their blogpost, and it will never play a song by the same artist twice. The algorithm will also spread songs by the same artist out in a semi-random fashion.

```
import random

songs = {
    'Artist a': ['song a1', 'song a2'],
    'Artist b': ['song b1', 'song b2', 'song b3'],
    'Artist c': ['song c1', 'song c2'],
    'Artist d': ['song d1', 'song d2', 'song d3', 'song d4'],
    'Artist e': ['song e1', 'song e2', 'song e3']
 }

def shuffle(artist_song_dict):
    """ Shuffles songs in a semi-random fashion while keeping songs by the same artist spread out, as described in
    https://labs.spotify.com/2014/02/28/how-to-shuffle-songs/
    artist_song_dict must be a dictionary where the key = the artist name and the value = a list of songs
    """
    lineup = {} #each song will be stored in this dictionary with a value between 0 and 1 representing the song's position in the lineup
    variation = .3 #a 30% variation will be added to all songs
    for artist in artist_song_dict:
        songs = artist_song_dict[artist]
        random.shuffle(songs)

        #distance between songs in the lineup, if we were to space the songs out evenly
        spread = 1/len(songs)

        #this is reffered to as the offset in the article, but I found this has a different purpose than what the article says
        #without this, the number of songs an artists has in the lineup affects the probablity that their songs will appear sooner/later in the lineup versus other artists
        artist_variation = random.uniform(0, spread-variation)

        for i, song in enumerate(songs):
            #the random 30% variation
            song_variation = random.uniform(0, spread*variation)

            #assign this song the next evenly spaced spot in the lineup plus our variations
            lineup[song] = i*(spread) + artist_variation + song_variation

    return sorted(lineup, key=lineup.get)

print(shuffle(songs))
```

### As a Generator

This is pretty cool. I came up with a completely separate algorithm that implements shuffling as a generator.

**Pros to this algorithm over the above one**

- you can dynamically add or remove songs to the lineup. Songs added will be appropriately shuffled.
- It's slightly faster
- The algorithm shuffles songs one at a time, so you get to enjoy additional performance gains from only shuffling what you listen to, if you find that you often listen to only a few of the songs in your library.

**cons**

- The algorithm can repeat songs by the same artist as you get down to the last few songs in the lineup
- The algorithm is very prone to following the same sequence of artists. So a song by artist a gets played, then artist b, then artist c, then artist a, and so on. This isn't always the case, but generally it is.
- Instead of evenly distributing songs by the same artist, there is a chance that an artist could be skipped each time we cycle through all of the artists. If an artists has fewer songs left there is a greater likelihood they will be skipped. There will still be a good amount of space between songs by the same artist (until we get to the end of the lineup where this algorithm starts to break down).

Ok, so here is the algorithm. It works my smashing all of the songs together in a single list, and then it keeps track of the biggest amount of songs an artist has in the lineup. We take this number (the biggest number of songs an artists has in the lineup), and we move forwards in the lineup by this number + a random variation.

The likelihood that we will play a song by a specific artist is consistent with the amount of songs they have left in the lineup, and since we are moving through a list that is organized by artist, it leaves some time before we are able to get back to playing a song by the same artist. Because of these items, the lineup is kept shuffled instead of random.

```
def shuffle2(artist_song_dict):
    """ Returns a generator that will shuffles the songs in a semi-random fashion while keeping some distance between songs by the same artist.
    artist_song_dict must be a dictionary where the key = the artist name and the value = a list of songs
    """

    # pairs is a list of all of the (artist, song) tuples
    pairs = []
    for artist, songs in artist_song_dict.items():
        random.shuffle(songs)
        pairs.extend([(artist, song) for song in songs])

    #cpy is a copy of the artist_song_dict
    #that we will use to keep track of how many songs each artist
    #has left that has not already been shuffled
    cpy = deepcopy(artist_song_dict)
    cpy_vals = cpy.values()

    n = 0 #n is the index of which song from our pairs list gets played next
    while len(pairs):
        #move forwards by the most songs an artist has left to be shuffled
        #anything smaller than this could lead to two songs being placed twice by the same artist
        n += max([len(l) for l in cpy_vals])
        #add a 30% random value that will result in an artists being skipped every once in a while
        n = int(n * random.uniform(1, 1.3))
        #wrap around the end of the list if exceed the length of our pairs list
        n = n % len(pairs)

        #now that we have our n number we can grab the artist and song
        artist = pairs[n][0]
        song = pairs[n][1]
        #we remove this info from the cpy dictionary
        cpy[artist].remove(song)
        #and we remove this info from the pairs list, and return the (artist, song) tuple.
        yield pairs.pop(n)
```

And if you want a version that is more optimized for speed -- and more confusing to understand, here you go.

```
def shuffle2_optimized(artist_song_dict):
    """ optimized version of the shuffle2 function """

    pairs = [(k,random.sample(v, len(v))) for k, v in artist_song_dict.items()]
    lens = [len(l) for l in artist_song_dict.values()]
    artists = list(artist_song_dict.keys())

    n = 0
    numb_pairs = len(pairs)
    max_lens = max(lens)-1
    while numb_pairs:
        n = int((n+max_lens) * (1 + .3*random.random())) % numb_pairs
        ret = pairs.pop(n)

        art_idx = artists.index(ret[0])
        lens[art_idx] -= 1
        if lens[art_idx]+1 == max_lens:
            max_lens = max(lens)

        numb_pairs = len(pairs)
        yield ret
```

Comment: Could you explain what the meaning of 100 and 3 is?

I guess the number 3 is the number of "if statements", but I do not know 100.

Comment: 100 was just an arbitrary value to represent the maximum number on the scale I used to assign each song a weight representing where in the lineup the song was going to appear. Although, because of the offset, you can go above 100, so it's not a true maximum. Note that decimal numbers are being used on this scale. I could have made the scale from 0 to 1, instead. Perhaps that would have made more sense. The 3 is to get a 30% variance. The article talks about a 20-30% variance. I've added in the comments now, so it should make more sense now.

Comment: AMAZING... thank you

Comment: You're welcome. It was a fun challenge for me to implement this. 

I've updated my answer with a better version. In the old version, the probability that an artist would appear at any given position in the lineup was not consistent. 

The article didn't mention this, but perhaps it would be an improvement to have one song play from each of the artists before we start repeating songs by the same artists. I'll have to think about that idea some more...

Comment: I am curious about the edit function. I'm sorry

Comment: Is it impossible to cancel?

Comment: I don't understand what your asking. There isn't an edit function. The shuffle function returns a list of songs. Once you get the list back, it's up to the program implementing this algorithm to control cancelling the playlist, as well as skipping songs, pausing, etc.

Comment: I do have a different algorithm that I came up with that will perform the shuffling. It's not as good of an algorithm, but it uses a Python generator, which means your able to dynamically add and remove songs in real-time. It's kind of cool. I'll post the code I created for this algorithm on Saturday.

Comment: Also, could you +1 this answer if it was useful to you.